# Role of zu+infinitive in example

Tags: grammar-identification, infinitive

> Auch dieser Junge war ein guter Grund, **sich von den Potters fernzuhalten;** *mit einem solchen Kind sollte ihr Dudley nicht in Berührung kommen.*

My knowledge of Infinitivsätze is not that thorough; i often see them used as complements of a verb(subjekt/objekt) or as Adverbialsätze starting with um/ohne/(an)statt/außer...zu. but here that doesn't seem to be the case. Infinitivsätze mit zu don't always have to be either a complemental clause/adverbial clause? what other roles/purposes do they fill?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works literally the same as in English. In English you could express this as follows: "This boy too was a good reason **to** keep away from the Potters."

(That is not how this is actually worded in the original, which talks about a good reason "for keeping the Potters away". This is just a matter of book translations not being literal.)

You can use a "zu" construction to further explain a noun like "Grund". German and English work very similarly in this regard.

Comment: thank you alot. very appreciated